# ImageMagick replace white with red not working

Tags: imagemagick

This is the image:

[image]

The light part isn't perfect white but `FDFDFD`

I tried:

old.png -fuzz 5% -fill red -opaque white new.png

but the white becomes black!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image is greyscale. Try making it colour first:

```
magick old.png -colorspace sRGB -fuzz 5% -fill red -opaque white new.png
```

Comment: Should be -colorspace sRGB